# User Registration Flow | Send data to analytics or to an endpoint for tracking

Tags: curity

We are trying to evaluate Curity for OAuth based login and are defaulting to Curity's built-in user registration flow, however have a requirement to send the registration info for tracking purposes (mainly email-id).
There are two options -

1. Add a script to registration form that will pick up the data and send it for tracking
2. Custom action tied to registration (or registration event) that makes a call to end point to send data

How can I use any of these approach in Curity. Or if there a best practice defined that allows me to capture information on registration.

Haven't been able to figure out anything based on examples and documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches are valid and can be done with customizations in the Curity Identity Server.

To add a script to the registration form, have a look at this example that shows how a script is embedded in a template: https://github.com/curityio/microblink-scan-id/blob/main/src/main/resources/templates/authentication-action/microblink-scan-id/microblink-scan-id/get.vm

Here is the documentation that explains how the templating system works and how to override its elements:
https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/developer-guide/front-end-development/index.html

In your case, you will want to override templates of the `html-form` authenticator, as this is the one that takes care of the registration form.

The option of adding actions is also viable. Have a look at this repo that shows an advanced flow with different actions that run depending on whether the user registers or not:
https://github.com/curityio/account-linking-recipes/blob/main/doc/4-migrating-to-passwordless-behavior.md

Comment: Thanks!! Overriding the template worked for me.